# Questions about debugging/reverse-engineering binaries

Tags: discussion, scope, debugging-questions

I have a debugging questions, but am not sure if it is on-topic or not. Since some people tend to be uptight about—what are in their opinion are—“bad” questions, I figured I would check with meta first.

There is a closed-source freeware program which I like a lot and am generally content with, but it has one really annoying bug. I suspect the bug is due to using a 32-bit signed value instead of an unsigned value, which should make it relatively easy to fix, but unfortunately development has long since been discontinued, so there is no hope of an official fix.

The bug is sufficiently annoying that I want to dig in and fix it myself by debugging the executable to find the code that handles that value, and make a patch to treat it as unsigned (it may be very easy or difficult, no way to tell without seeing the specific assembler instructions).

I believe it is on-topic because it is a tracing and debugging question. There don’t seem to be any rules that questions are only valid if they involve the source-code, so it should be valid here.

So what do you think, is it okay here or will someone freak out and tell me to jog on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends a little bit on your actual question but I doubt we can help with a question to trace and debug code for you.

You could have some success if your question is showing the actual disassembly and you're looking for a way to squeeze in some bytes to alter the assembly language without taking up more bytes.

If you're also looking for help in finding the exact location of the bug you might find [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) helpful but before you post read the help/on-topic, research and/or ask (reputation permitting) on their meta.

Comment: Ah, I didn’t know there was a specific reverse-engineering SE site now. Obviously that is a better fit. Thanks.

Comment: What about the legal/moral side? I guess many people frown upon questions which are implicitly asking about how to violate software licenses; rev'eng is almost always explicitly prohibited. What if I asked "There's a program I'd really like to use for free, but it has this annoying copy protection. Can you help me to remove it?"

Comment: That would probably be marked as spam, assuming it was well formed enough to be technically a good fit for the site. At the first three companies I worked at, we've had to reverse engineer some bit of our older code from some forgotten time because the source was long gone or not reproduceable. It happens.

Comment: @HannoBinder sure, that can be a problem. But I'm not a lawyer,  I assume good faith and we have no reliable way to judge if the OP's action are legit.

Comment: @HannoBinder, Reverse engineering is not always illegal, even in the US. See https://www.eff.org/issues/coders/reverse-engineering-faq#faq6 That being said, I'm not sure if the user is trying to fix a bug of an unsupported app (as he claims), or change the score (or the currency) in a game. The advice he is seeking could help him do either of those things.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk That's right. I was referring to those non-open software licenses, most of which contain a paragraph about rev'eng. Just wanted to bring up the issue, and I gather from these comments that we're focusing on technical issues here and not so much on moral and legal judgements.

Comment: @HannoBinder, I just wanted to make sure. As some of the examples I've given you had a clause against reverse engineering, but ultimately those clauses were not always enforced by the courts.